# Testing HATEOAS in SpringBoot 1.4 does not work when using TestRestTemplate

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, hateoas

I've using

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to create hypermedia links in my SpringBoot 1.4 application. It works fine for production but I have some issues when testing it by a SpringBoot test.

I have a simple test to check HATEOAS links

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MessageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private MessageService messageService;

    @Test
    public void testHypermedia() throws Exception {
        final Message message = createSimpleMessage("1");

        given(messageService.getMessagesOfGroupForContact(message.getGroupIdentifier(), message.getCreator().getId())).willReturn(Collections.singletonList(message));

        final MessageDto messageDto = testRestTemplate.exchange("/api/messages?groupIdentifier={groupId}&contactId={contactId}", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MessageDto>>() {
        }, message.getGroupIdentifier(), message.getCreator().getId()).getBody().get(0);

        assertThat(messageDto.getLinks().size()).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(messageDto.getLink("self")).isNotNull();
        assertThat(messageDto.getLink("self").getHref()).endsWith("/api/message/1?contactId=creator_1");
    }
}
```

This test is working fine. URL */api/messages?groupIdentifier={groupId}&contactId={contactId}* returns a list of MessageDaos.

But when switching to tests url */api/message/{messageId}?contactId={contactId}* that returns only one element getLinks() is empty:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MessageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private MessageService messageService;

    @Test
    public void testHypermedia() throws Exception {
        final Message message = createSimpleMessage("1");

        given(messageService.getMessagesOfGroupForContact(message.getGroupIdentifier(), message.getCreator().getId())).willReturn(Collections.singletonList(message));

        //final ResponseEntity<MessageDto> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange("/api/message/{messageId}?contactId={contactId}", HttpMethod.GET, null, MessageDto.class, message.getId(), message.getCreator().getId());
        final MessageDto messageDto = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/api/message/{messageId}?contactId={contactId}", MessageDto.class, message.getId(), message.getCreator().getId()).getBody();

        assertThat(messageDto.getLinks().size()).isEqualTo(1); // breaking
        assertThat(messageDto.getLink("self")).isNotNull();
        assertThat(messageDto.getLink("self").getHref()).endsWith("/api/message/1?contactId=creator_1");
    }
}
```

It does not work when using getForEntity(...) nor using exchange(...). Both of this methods return a correct MessageDto with missing links.

What is wrong?

Comment: What does the request and response payloads look like over the wire? Best way to check is to set DEBUG log level for `org.apache.http.wire`.

Comment: @ShawnClark Thanks for your response. I've updated log level to debug but I don't see any log output for `org.apache.http.wire`.

Comment: Have the same problem here. Works with mockMvc but not the testRestTemplate.